# How do I get step count for specific time using Google Fitness API?

Tags: java, android, google-api, google-fit

I want to get step count for specific time like 4 to 6 PM.
I have checked related sample projects from Google official github account and other sources but mostly, It was about fetching daily step count or calories burned.
But instead I want to read step count for specific hours. Is it possible to get this data? If so, how would you do it?

Answer (score 1):

Try using this:---
      DataReadRequest readRequest = new DataReadRequest.Builder()

```
       .aggregate(DataType.TYPE_STEP_COUNT_DELTA, 
  DataType.AGGREGATE_STEP_COUNT_DELTA)

       .bucketByTime(1, TimeUnit.DAYS)
       .setTimeRange(startTime, endTime, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS)
       .build();


DataReadResult dataReadResult =
    Fitness.HistoryApi.readData(mClient, readRequest).await(1, TimeUnit.MINUTES);
```

where start and end time is the time in millis

and use the dataReadResult object to obtain your values

Comment: so starttime and endtime will be set as normal value or some specific value?